# How to check whether a given word contains in String?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
function count()
{
    var listOfWords, paragraph, listOfWordsArray, paragraphArray;
    var wordCounter=0;

    listOfWords = document.getElementById("wordsList").value;

    //Split the words
    listOfWordsArray = listOfWords.split("\n");

    //Get the paragrah text
    paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph").value;
    paragraphArray = paragraph.split(" ");

    //check whether paragraph contains words in list
    for(var i=0; i<listOfWordsArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(paragraph.contains(wordListArray[i]))
        {
                wordCounter++;
        }
    }

    window.alert("Number of Contains: "+wordCounter);
}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<center>
<p> Enter your Word List here </p>
<br />
<textarea id="wordsList" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>

<br />
<p>Enter your paragraph here</p>
<textarea id="paragraph" cols="100" rows="15"></textarea>

<br />
<br />
<button id="btn1"  onclick="count()">Calculate Percentage</button>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, what I am trying to do is counting how any number of words are in `paragraph` which are also included in `wordList`. words in `wordList` are separated by new line.

However, I am not getting anything as the output here. I am not into web and scripting languages much so I failed to find what is going behind.

How can I count how many words are in `paragraph` which are also included in `wordList`? And please explain why it is not getting displayed?

Comment: Suppose you have data like this "If this is your string If this is your string your" in paragraph and wordlist are {If , your} then o/p is "If : 2" and "your : 3" , Am I correct or wrong ?

Comment: This may be closed under the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had a typo

```
//check whether paragraph contains words in list
for(var i=0; i<listOfWordsArray.length; i++)
{
    if(paragraph.contains(wordListArray[i]))
    {
```

see `wordListArray` doesn't exist, it should be `listOfWordsArray`

see here http://jsfiddle.net/PW7jZ/

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf` method of string if you just want occurrence. Use `RegExp` to check the *whole* word only. Change your conditional like this (counts whole word):

```
//check whether paragraph contains words in list
for (var i = 0; i < listOfWordsArray.length; i++) {
    re = new RegExp("\\b" + listOfWordsArray[i] + "\\b");
    if (paragraph.match(re)) {
        wordCounter++;
    }
}
```

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/EuhEE/

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the textarea is only going to have text in it,use this

```
var count = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML.split(' ').length;
```

If the textarea can have HTML tags in it, you're going to have to traverse its children looking for text nodes:

```
function get_text(el) {
    ret = "";
    var length = el.childNodes.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var node = el.childNodes[i];
        if(node.nodeType != 8) {
            ret += node.nodeType != 1 ? node.nodeValue : get_text(node);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
var words = get_text(document.getElementById('content'));
var count = words.split(' ').length;
```

This is the same logic that the jQuery library uses to achieve the effect of its text() function. jQuery is a pretty awesome library that in this case is not necessary. However, if you find yourself doing a lot of DOM manipulation or AJAX then you might want to check it out.